Dockerfile dependencies: Building my frontend image requires the backend to be running
Context
I'm trying to deploy an application which has a REST backend and a frontend. I use a docker-compose file. The frontend uses Nuxt to generate a typed TS client from an OpenAPI (Swagger) file. This is a requirement to build the frontend application. The OpenAPI file is made available by our backend, so the backend must be running to allow retrieving the OpenAPI file to be used during the frontend build.
Issue
How can I specify in my frontend Dockerfile or in my docker-compose file that the backend image must be entirely built and then be run and be reachable by the process building the frontend image?

This isn't usually allowed in a Docker context; an image build runs in a context where it can't reach any other container.  Can you check the extracted OpenAPI file into source control, so you can get a fully reproducible build without external dependencies?
